# Best Way To Run Length Encode Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, run-length-encoding

I've created an table that tracks the various attributes of objects over time.

```
 Id | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 | StartDate  | EndDate
------------------------------------------------------------------
 01 |   100      |   Null     |   Null     | 2004-02-03 | 2006-04-30
 01 |   100      |   Null     |    D       | 2006-05-01 | 2010-11-06
 01 |   150      |   Null     |    D       | 2010-11-07 | Null
 02 |   700      |   5600     |   Null     | 1998-09-27 | 2002-01-27
```

New data (~10s of thousands of records) come in each day. What I want to do is compare each record to the current data for that id, and then:

a) Do nothing if the attributes match.
b) If the attributes are different, update the current record so that the EndDate is the current date, and create a new record with the new attributes.
c) Create a new record if there isn't any data for that id.

My question is, what is the most efficient way to do this?

I can write a script that goes through each record, does the comparison, and the updates the table as appropriate, but I fell like this is brute-force, rather than an intelligent solution.

Would this be a good place to use a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

How do you process data?  As it comes in or in batch?

If it is as it comes in, then I would do a set of checks on the most likely attribute to change and to the least likely (just to optimize the checking a bit) and update as needed.  10's of thousands is not enough data to worry about slowing down too much.  This is the straight forward approach.

If you process as a batch (like at end of business each day), sort the data by ID then descending end date. Delete all other instances of ID and only care about the latest one.  No intermediary data would matter.

Example: you have 2 entries for id 1, one with endDate Jan 1 other with endDate Jan 25.  Look at Jan 25 entry first and update if needed.  Jan 1 entry is too old to care about at that point.